# swap mips variables not being saved

Tags: mips

```
    .text
main:
    la  $a0,n1
    la  $a1,n2
    jal     swap
    li  $v0,1   # print n1 and n2; should be 27 and 14
    lw  $a0,n1
    syscall
    li  $v0,11
    li  $a0,' '
    syscall
    li  $v0,1
    lw  $a0,n2
    syscall
    li  $v0,11
    li  $a0,'\n'
    syscall
    li  $v0,10  # exit
    syscall

swap:
    xor $a0 $a0 $a1
    xor $a1 $a0 $a1
    xor $a0 $a0 $a1
    jr $ra


L1: 

    .data
n1: .word   14
n2: .word   27
```

ok so my goal was to add the goal to swap

however, no matter what I do with the variables inside swap it doesn't seem to be saved
i am editing a0 and a1, shouldn't that work?

the code always prints 14 and 27

Comment: You're only swapping the *pointers* `a0`, `a1` in your `swap` subroutine - you're not actually swapping the *contents* of `n1`, `n2`.

Comment: You need to load the values pointed at by a1, a2 into two temporary registers, then store these two values back to a2, a1.

Comment: do i u use t0 and t1 inside of swap? i mean i don't see why i need a temporary register I'm really new to mips. maybe an example?